# Cálculo do volume de um terreno irregular

Tags: c

O código consiste em calcular o volume de uma superfície irregular onde estou usando uma matriz `2 x 2` de tamanho máximo `1000 x 1000`, que representa um retângulo, portanto a área máxima do terreno é `1.000.000 m²`, e devo usar uma variável `y` livre, que representa a altura do terreno, como o terreno é irregular o `y` varia, em regiões de declives e aclives do terreno.

Quero calcular o volume total do terreno, onde devo utilizar um delta incremental aplicado às coordenadas `X`, `Y` e `Z`. A cada passo da aplicação do delta às coordenadas, deverá ser feito um cálculo/adição do volume de um pequeno cubo de volume delta³ ao volume total do terreno, não ultrapassando as dimensões do terreno ou o cálculo ficará errado, onde aqui também para a coordenada `Y`, devo  calcular uma reta de interpolação entre duas alturas `Y` de modo a determinar o limite de cubos adicionados para o cálculo do volume, ou seja, um limite para a progressão do loop que fará a varredura sistemática da altura do terreno.

Quando um cubo transpor o limite da coordenada `Y` interpolada será a hora de terminar o loop que incrementa a coordenada `Y`.

Eu estou com dúvida em como fazer isso eu escrevi um código, abaixo segue a parte do loop, entretanto ocorre um erro e estou com dúvida de como consertar:

```
for(i=0; i<x; i++){ // x representa a largura do terreno
    for(j=0; j<z; j++){ // z representa a profundidade do terreno
        fscanf(y, "%.2f\t", altitude[i][j]); // Armazena os valores das coordenadas x e z na altura y ( DÚVIDA NESSA LINHA, SEMPRE QUE TENTO ARMAZENAR NA VARIÁVEL Y, OCORRE ERRO )
    }
} 

for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    for(j=0; j<z; j++){
        delta = aux - altitude[i][j];
        volume = volume +(altitude[i][j]*delta);
        aux=altitude[i][j];
    }
}

printf("\n O volume do terreno é: %f\n", volume);
```

Comment: Qual o erro que a aparece quando você compila?

Comment: Basicamente ocorre o erro  nessa linha fscanf(y, "%.2f\t", altitude[ i ] [ j ]);  o programa não compila, e também tenho dúvida se apenas esse loop que eu escrevi já é o bastante para resolver meu problema.

Comment: É, realmente a sua pergunta não tá muito clara. Primeiramente, tá ok, o programa não compila... mas qual é a mensagem de erro do compilador? Em segundo lugar, o que vc quer fazer nessa linha do `fscanf`? Se vc só quer armazenar o valor do array na variável `y`, por que não fez simplesmente `y = altitude[i][j]`?. Sobre a questão do cálculo, você está considerando o terreno como sendo dividido em porções (as células do array) discretas, certo? Talvez se vc preparar um desenho ilustrativo de como a sua matriz representa o seu terreno isso ajude (até vc mesmo) no entendimento do problema.

Comment: `fscanf(f, "%f" ,  &( altitude[i][j] ))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem o que você deseja fazer na linha com a instrução `fscanf`, mas caso esteja tentando gravar o resultado em um arquivo, o melhor seria usar a instrução `fputs`. Dá uma olhadinha [aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm).

Mas se você apenas quer calcular o volume total do terreno, basta você somar todas as alturas que você armazenou no array. Algo assim:

```
// inicializa volume com 0 para acumular no loop
int volume = 0;
for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    for(j=0; j<z; j++){
      // adiciona o volume de cada área
      volume += altitude[i][j];
    }
}
```

No final deste loop, a variável `volume` terá o volume total do terreno.

Comment: Nessa linha eu quero armazenar o valor do array na variável y, que é a altura, pois a altura está variando e preciso levar em consideração ela para o cálculo do volume posteriormente.

Comment: E também preciso levar em conta o delta incremental para o cálculo do volume, esse delta incremental é análogo a uma soma de Riemann onde para calcular o valor de uma integral você divide a curva em vários retângulos.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, cada elemento do array terá a altura no ponto x,z. Se for isso, não existe a necessidade do delta, pois a soma das alturas de todos os pontos te dará o volume total. No cálculo, a divisão ao infinito é feito para calcular a área da curva (ou neste caso, o volume de uma superfície), mas a interpolação é limitada pela dimensão do array, onde cada elemento do array é uma área mínima a ser adicionada no somatório. Neste caso, como falei antes, basta somar todos os elementos do array para chegar ao volume total.

Comment: Por exemplo, se o seu terreno tiver uma dimensão de 10x10, e cada ponto tiver uma altura de 10 (estou simplificando), somando cada valor do array você chegaria a 1000, que é o volume do cubo de 10x10x10 de comprimento.